# Match 2 colums in 2 excel sheets and paste a third

Tags: excel

I have two excel sheets both with matching product numbers. What I need to do is match the product numbers and then copy a column from the first sheet to the second.

My example:
Column C in the first sheet contains product numbers
Column A in the second sheet contains product numbers
I want to match C & A and then copy column B from the first to the second sheet.

Sorry if this has been answered before, my knowledge is basic but I am trying to learn

Thanks for any help.
CD

Comment: Do you want a [multiple criteria `Index/Match`](https://www.deskbright.com/excel/index-match-multiple-criteria/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your numbers to match start in C2 (headers in row 1) and numbers to copy in AC2 on Sheet1, this should do what you want. Paste it into AC2 on Sheet2 and then drag copy to the length of column A on Sheet2.

```
=IF(IFNA(MATCH(A2,Sheet1!C:C,0), FALSE), INDIRECT("Sheet1!AC"&MATCH(A2, Sheet1!C:C, 0)), "Not Found")
```

Note this will give "Not Found" for a value on Sheet2 which is not found on Sheet1, you can change that by just replacing the string `"Not Found"` in the formula with whatever you want (e.g. 0).

Comment: Thanks Nick, I cant get it to work. I have Column C Sheet1 and Column A sheet2 and AC is the column to copy from sheet1 to sheet2. This stuff does my head in.

Answer (score 0):

**Formula:**

You can use OFFSET with IF. In B1 of sheet 2 for example you could put, drag down for as many rows as required,

```
=IF(A1=Sheet1!C1,OFFSET(Sheet1!A1,0,COLUMNS(Sheet1!A:AC)-1,1,1))
```

If you set your data up as a table in sheet 2 (Ctrl + T with an populated cell selected) then add this formula to the appropriate column it will autofilter down the formula.

**Or:**

With code in a standard module:

```
Public Sub AddFormula()
    Dim rng As Range
    With Worksheets("Sheet2")
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Columns(1).Cells) > 0 Then
            For Each rng In Intersect(.Columns(1), .UsedRange)
                If Not IsEmpty(rng) And Not IsError(rng) Then        'assume ignore empty cells
                    If rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(rng.Row, "C") Then Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(rng.Row, "AC").Copy rng.Offset(, 1) 'determine where you want value to go
                End If
            Next rng
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

**Note:**

This is based on your comment that you are comparing sheet2 col A with sheet1 col C and copying sheet1 col AC if match.

Answer (score -2):

I assume that the product numbers in both sheets are unique. If that, I suggest use the offset and match formulas to achieve what you want.

sorry for my half-baked answer due to i just typed them with phone and it is not convenient to input complicated style, here is the additional information:

1. the **match** formula is used to query the location of the target product number in the original sheet( sheet 1 in your case above);
2. after we located the position of the target product number, extract the information you wanted through the **offset** formula.

here are the specific process:

Sheet 1 represent the original information and sheet 2 represent the target one. What we required to do is copy the info in col D of sheet 1 to col D of sheet through the product:

`OFFSET($D$5,MATCH(I6,$D$5:$D$16,0)-1,1,1,1)
OFFSET($D$5,MATCH(I7,$D$5:$D$16,0)-1,1,1,1)
OFFSET($D$5,MATCH(I8,$D$5:$D$16,0)-1,1,1,1)
OFFSET($D$5,MATCH(I9,$D$5:$D$16,0)-1,1,1,1)
OFFSET($D$5,MATCH(I10,$D$5:$D$16,0)-1,1,1,1)`

or you can refer to the output directly:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzQrg.png)

for more information about these two formulas, you can refer to the help of excel of google.

Comment: Yes, the numbers are unique. I have no idea how to use these functions.

Comment: i admitted i typed a half - baked answer just now and i have make some additional information as supplement.